# Django/Docker: migration not detected and not applied

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

Stack: Django/Docker/Docker-compose/Postgresql (not in container)

I have made modifications, including models updates, saved and push to my remote Gitlab repository.

Then, I pulled modification from my Gitlab repo on the preprod server and I can see that I have the modified version on the server.

But when I stop and restart the container, it does not detect any changes and does not apply the migrations.
I also checked, the `entrypoint.preprod.sh` file contains the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands.

I have tried by rebuilding it with `docker-compose build` then run it, but it doesn't work anymore.

I tried by connecting directly to my container (`docker exec -it web sh`) but `makemigrations` are not detected and migrations are therefore not applied.

I must be missing something but what?

**docker-compose-preprod.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        restart: always
        container_name: virage_web
        build: 
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.preprod
        restart: always
        command: gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - app_volume:/usr/src/app
            - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
            - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
        expose:
            - 8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod
        entrypoint: [ "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.preprod.sh" ]
        depends_on:
            - redis
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8000/"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 50
            
    redis:
        container_name: virage_redis
        image: "redis:alpine"

    celery:
        container_name: virage_celery
        build: 
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.preprod
        command: celery -A core worker -l info
        volumes:
            - app_volume:/usr/src/app
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod
        depends_on:
            - web
            - redis

    celery-beat:
        container_name: virage_celery-beat
        build: 
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.preprod
        command: celery -A core beat -l info
        volumes:
            - app_volume:/usr/src/app
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod
        depends_on:
            - web
            - redis           
  
    nginx:
        container_name: virage_nginx
        build: ./nginx
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
            - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
        ports:
            - 1350:80
        depends_on:
            - web


volumes:
    static_volume:
    media_volume:
    app_volume:
```

**Dockerfile.preprod**

```
# Pull the official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# Set a work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc g++ python3-dev musl-dev

RUN apk --update add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev musl-dev libgcc openssl-dev curl postgresql-client
RUN apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev nano
RUN pip3 install psycopg2 psycopg2-binary

# install xgettext for i18n
RUN apk add gettext

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements/ requirements/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements/preprod.txt

# Copy the entrypoint.sh file
COPY entrypoint.preprod.sh .

# Copy the initdata sql file
COPY initdata.preprod.sql .

# Copy the project's files
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.preprod.sh
```

**entrypoint.preprod.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

# python manage.py flush --no-input
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
python manage.py makemessages -l fr
python manage.py compilemessages



exec "$@"
```

Comment: Have you run `django-admin showmigrations`? That will show which migrations have been applied or not (or which migrations django _believes_ has been applied).
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-showmigrations

Comment: No but I can see in postgresdatabase (django-migrations models) that migrations have not been applied